# Why isn't this binding working in MVVM?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I'm setting up a binding to a ViewModel object from a WPF View, but the binding doesn't seem to be firing. I haven't done much work in MVVM, so I thought I'd ask to see if there's a reason why the binding to the image's source property isn't firing when the page is loaded.

Here's the page's XAML:

```
<Page x:Class="DallasPrintManager.PrintPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:DallasPrintManager.ViewModel"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="900"
  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource PrintPage}}">
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition  />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageDisplay}" />
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

And here's the ViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Input;
using DallasPrintManager.Commands;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

public class PrintPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BitmapImage _imageDisplay;

    public PrintPageViewModel()
    {
        ImageDisplay = getImage();
    }

    private BitmapImage getImage()
    {
        try
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            byte[] imageData = wc.DownloadData("http://localhost/TestImage.tif");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage wpfImg = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            wpfImg.BeginInit();
            wpfImg.StreamSource = ms;
            wpfImg.EndInit();
            return wpfImg;
            //return (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error fetching document:\n\n" + e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e.Source == "System.Drawing")
                MessageBox.Show("Error reading document.");
            Console.Out.Write(e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    public BitmapImage ImageDisplay
    {
        get
        {
            return _imageDisplay;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _imageDisplay)
            {
                _imageDisplay = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ImageDisplay");
            }
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

The viewmodel is instantiated in app.xaml, and bound to by the print page.

Comment: Look in your Debug Output window. Do you see any binding errors? Please post them here.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin - I think you can go ahead and post that as an answer: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Main' property not found on 'object' ''PrintPageViewModel' (HashCode=20670010)'. BindingExpression:Path=Main; DataItem='PrintPageViewModel' (HashCode=20670010); target element is 'PrintPage' (Name=''); target property is 'DataContext' (type 'Object')

Comment: Done! :-) [here goes the filler to 15 characters]

Comment: For future reference... http://i.imgur.com/UAxJO.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in your Debug Output window. Do you see any binding errors? They pretty much tell you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If the Debug Output Window is not shown you can enable it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>.

For further information add `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` inside your XAML and `diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to your binding:

```
<Page x:Class="DallasPrintManager.PrintPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:DallasPrintManager.ViewModel"
  xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
  [...]
  DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource PrintPage}}">
```

and:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageDisplay, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" />
```

You should also  make sure your properties of the bindings implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` if the bindings make use of `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. Otherwise they will not update.

You can even create a dummyConverter:

```
public class DebugDummyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    Debugger.Break();
                    return value;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                    Debugger.Break();
                    return value;
            }
    }
```

and add it inside your binding `Converter={StaticResource DebugDummyConverter}` to get information about your value of the binding, but this only works if the binding is correctly set otherwise you will not get any information.

See http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/ for more details.